# Casting object to Integer for assignment in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, integer, streaming

I'm fairly new to Java, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.  I am trying to create a method that will read raw data based on the type passed in. What I have is:

```
// should update o to contain value read from bytes
int read(byte[] data, Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        Integer i = (Integer)o;
        i=(byte[0] << 8) + (byte[1]);
        return 2;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, Eclipse is complaining that the local variable `i` is never read.   I tried casting `o` to `Integer`, and doing a direct assignment to that, but that also didn't work.  I'm wondering what the proper way of doing this is?

Comment: What is the purpose of `i`? If you remove it entirely, what changes in your program?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(o instanceof Integer)`?

Comment: Eclipse complains because the variable is, indeed, never read. Please note that you defined `i` and return simply `2`. Should you return `i`, instead, there would be no complaints. Also, as @EdwinDalorzo said, shouldn't `val` be `o`?

Comment: Plus, since you're fairly new to Java I won't be picky with the code, but bear in mind that `instanceof` is an example of RTTI (Real Time Type Identificaiton) which is highly discouraged due to some backlashes. In the future, please prefer "Method Overloading" over this. If you don't know what that is yet, it's OK. But keep an eye for it in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I had simplified the example a bit, and introduced a bug, it should be o.   What I want to do is to populate the integer that I am passing in, so if I did read(bytes,val), I would want val to be updated to contain whatever was in bytes.   The return value is the number of bytes read

Comment: Gamb -- is there any documentation on the backlashes that can be caused by RTTI?  In my real program, I would have wanted a variable list argument, so that I could do `read(int1, int2, string1, double1)` for example.   It would be nice to do this in one statement, but if there's reasons against it, I could move those to be four or five independent statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Eclipse is complaining that the local variable i is never read.

That is true - you assign to variable `i`, but you never read the value assigned to it. Moreover, you assign to it twice - at the declaration, and on the second line, and both times the result of the assignment is ignored.

However, this is only a warning. It tells you that something is wrong with your program's logic, but it does not prevent you from running the program.

> I'm wondering what the proper way of doing this is?

Figure out what you want to do with the `Integer` coming in as `Object`, and change the return statement to depend on its value in some way.

Note that you can get rid of the warning simply by returning `i`. This would deal with only one of the two logical problems, though, so the solution may not be appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I see what I've done wrong now -- I want to update o to contain the value read in from bytes (like a dereference in c), but what I did will overwrite what I passed in (create a new instance).   Is there a way to update the value of the passed in integer?  (note: the return value is the number of bytes consumed, so it has to be 2).

Comment: I had to look up immutable.  I found a way around this -- pass in an array of one Integer instead of passing in an Integer...   Apperently arrays are mutable.   I'm likely breaking a dozen java conventions doing that, but it  works :-).